# Dynamic creation of Json files from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I want to create multiple JSON files from an array.

**Array** :

```
 [{
    "Reference": "Registration",
    "langkey": "REG_LBL",
    "English": "Company Registration",
    "Japanese": "会社登録"
}, {
    "Reference": "Registration",
    "langkey": "INFO_LBL",
    "English": "Company Information",
    "Japanese": "会社情報"
}]
```

I need to create two JSON files name English and Japanese(it will be dynamic) from above array.

**Desired Output**

*English.json*

```
{
'INFO_LBL' : 'Company Information',
'REG_LBL':'Company Registration'
}
```

*Japanese.json*

```
{
'INFO_LBL' : '会社情報',
'REG_LBL':'会社情報'
}
```

**Code**

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (key !=='Reference' && key !== 'langkey' ) {
            //{'REG_LBL':'Company Registration'}

            objects[obj['langkey']] = obj[key];
            fs.writeFileSync('lang/' + langkey + '.json', JSON.stringify(objects, null, 2), { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err) {
                if (err)
                { throw err; }
                console.log("completed")

            });

        }
    }
}
```

I am ale to create two JSON files but the content is overwritten by another.Please help to resolve this?

Comment: You are able to create two JSON files. If your array has more than one object for each language, you need to use an array of objects for each language and write this to your json file.

Comment: Where do you define your `langKey`?

Comment: can you include how you create your json file

Comment: this is in node js, you might wanna tag this as nodejs

Comment: writeFileSync does not accept a 4th argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 items in your array, and 2 languages both so do you need to have 4 json files? 2 for INFO_LBL (English & japanesh) and 2 for REG_LBL(English & japanesh) ? or do you just need 2 json files for the second item INFO_LBL (English & japanesh) ?

update: bellow is your solution

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var obj = data[i];
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (key !== 'Reference' && key !== 'langkey') {
            var newObject = {};
            var path = 'lang/' + key + '.json';
            if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
                var newObject = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path, 'utf8'));
            }
            newObject[obj.langkey] = obj[key];
            fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(newObject, null, 2), { encoding: 'utf8' });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer.  Nothing change but you just need to get the object already stored in json file if there are already stored.
PS: remove all lang/*.json files before

Answer (score 2):

```
var finalObject = {};//create new object

data.forEach(v => {
    var langkey = v.langkey;
    Object.keys(v).forEach(val => {
        if (val != 'langkey' && val != 'Reference') {
            if (finalObject[val]) {//find if language object is already created.If already created insert in it else create new
                let data = {};
                data[langkey] = v[val]
                finalObject[val] = Object.assign(finalObject[val], data)
            } else {
                finalObject[val] = {};
                finalObject[val][langkey] = v[val];
            }


        }
    })
})
Object.keys(finalObject).forEach(key => {
    fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, `/lang/${key}.json`), JSON.stringify(finalObject[key], null, 2), (err) => {
        if (err)
        { throw err; }
        console.log('completed');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works. I created separate objects for each using window['newVariable'];

```
var myArray = 

[{
    "Reference": "Registration",
    "langkey": "REG_LBL",
    "English": "Company Registration",
    "Japanese": "会社登録"
}, {
    "Reference": "Registration",
    "langkey": "INFO_LBL",
    "English": "Company Information",
    "Japanese": "会社情報"
}];

for(i=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
  window['myJSON' + i] = myArray[i];
}
console.log(myJSON0, myJSON1);
```

Here's what I got, two separate objects

[image]

Now all you have to do is stringify to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is getting overwritten, it would be because of the writeFileSync. You should be using appendFileSync or the a flag for writeFileSync